# Dynamically creating new tabs from ajax content

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm new to foundation and I think for the most part it's great.

I just have a question in regards to foundation's tabs, and I have read the documentation which was mostly talking about the markup construction to get the effect.

However, I have a situation where I have to create new dynamic tabs inside my app where data will be loaded using ajax and these tabs and their tabbed content will be created on the fly.

I would assume that if you create new tab elements on the fly, you would have to run some method that will create event handlers for the new tabs.

I was just wondering if there have any functions to allow update of the tab object so that that the events for the tabs will propagate to the newly created items?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the tabs through js/ajax yet?  The event handler for the tabs is attached to the document, not the tabs themselves.  It accomplishes the tab changing event through jQuery's event delegation. So what this means is that the clicking of a tab will bubble up to the document element and trigger the change.  This works even with dynamically added tabs.

So the short answer is:  Don't worry about the event handling. It will work even with tabs added after the page has loaded.